# Python libraries on windows failure

Tags: python

Could someone guide me on how to install libraries for Python on Windows? I tried with the command shell but i failed miserably. Basically i want to install multiple libraries. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to download prebuilt packages from: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

["Setuptools + Pip"](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/win/#setuptools-pip) may be also of interest.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically i want to install multiple libraries. Is it possible?

Yes it is possible, though it would be nice to explain better what you mean.

Simple method as iljau posted [pre-compiled binaries για Windows]

2nd method:  [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) and [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools). `pip install <your_library>`

Comment: Thank you too for the help.